# Facebook's Share link not refreshing title for cross posting

Tags: facebook, social-networking, sharing

I'm trying to figure out how to update the title of a cross posting.  If I use ShareThis to share my link, it is grabbing the title, description and image through open graph, but when I click on the link on Facebook to repost or anyone else does, it doesn't pick up the updated image or title.  Can this be updated or force through meta tags, og:tag or some other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this also when I've been playing around with the Feed posting.

If you log in with any other account you'll find that when you post the same link, it will show the updated photo.

It might also be worth using the linter/debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug  to see if this "jolts" Facebook in to action.

Let me know what happens :)

Comment: I have tried many times but still can't get this to work.  The debug tool works but it doesn't appear to work in reality.  Any other options would be appreciated.  Thanks!